# locking screen or elements with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I have a HTML page. By default `#B` is set as `display: none` and when I click on `#button`
`#B` is shown as overlay style via jQuery. Also I need to lock all elements except `#B`

```
<div id="A">
    <!-- Some HTML elements -->
    <a id="button">Button</a>
    <div id="B">
        <!-- Some HTML elements -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Can you seggest me a jquery plugin in order to do this?

Comment: [`blockUI` might do what you want](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/block/)

Comment: If by locking, you mean "can't interact with anything else behind it", a trick is to put a layer underneath that takes up the whole page. That way, when a user tries to click somewhere else, this layer takes all the clicks and nothing happens. It's the basic principal of all lightboxes.

Comment: @Matt, yes I tried but seem to be oriented to messages only, may be I am wrong.

Comment: @vyx.ca yes, I mean that can't interact with anything else behind it. How can I put a layer underneath?

Comment: I'll fiddle something for you. Give me a couple of minutes.

Comment: You can't really lock web content unless the elements aren't sent by the server yet.. anyone that knows about DOM will trick any attemps to lock elements. However, it is possible to make other people think this is locked by putting a floating division over the content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

David Thomas' answer is good but if you want the jQuery version of it, take a look at [this fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/cXNTh/4/)
Also, `:target` is not support in version earlier than IE9.

### HTML

```
<div id="A">
    <!-- Some HTML elements -->
    <a id="button" href="#">Button</a>
    <div id="B">
        <div id="background"></div>
        <div id="content">
            <p>This is a paragraph</p>
            <img src="http://fakeimg.pl/350x200/?text=This is an image" width="350" height="200" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
#A {}

#B, #background  {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    z-index:10;
}

#B  {
    display:none; 
}

#background  {
    background:#FFF;
    opacity:0.3;
}

#content {
    position:absolute;
    z-index:20;
    top:0; /* will be centered by jQuery */
    left:0; /* will be centered by jQuery */
}
```

### JAVASCRIPT

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('#button').click(function() {
        showOverlay();
    });

     //if you want to close the overlay if the user clicks the background
    $('#background').click(function() {
        $('#B').hide();
    }) 
});

function showOverlay() {
    $('#B').show();
    $('#content').css({
        top : ($(window).height() - $('#content').height()) / 2,
        left : ($(window).width() - $('#content').width()) / 2
    });
}
```

Comment: Your HTML wasn't indent correctly, and doesn't show. I've corrected it for you :)

Comment: It's good idea to handle the overlay layer with CSS, and use jQuery only for `click` event.

Comment: @Mojtaba I read [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_target.asp) that `:target` property is not supported  in Internet Explorer 8 and earlier versions. So seems to be better idea handle the overlay with jQuery.

Comment: @Overflow012 Yes, you are correct. But this answer didn't use `:target`. I want to say that the JS code in this example can write in a better way that involve JavaScript and CSS in the correct way. However this solution is really perfect.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this with pure CSS, in the majority of browsers (those that support the `:target` pseudo-selector), given the following (generic) HTML:

```
<div id="lock">
    <a href="#unlocked">Unlock</a>
</div>
<div id="unlocked" class="pageContent">
    <a href="#lock">Lock page</a>
    <p>This is the container element for page-content</p>
</div>
```

And CSS:

```
#lock {
    display: none;
}
#lock:target {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
    border: 10em solid rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
    text-align: center;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/4NPsv/1/)

It is, of course, worth reiterating the obvious: this content is on the user's machine, therefore you *can't* prevent their interaction with the content (assuming they know how to interact with the content, for example: right-click -> inspect element -> right-click in the web inspector -> 'delete node', or simply with JavaScript: `document.body.removeChild(document.getElementById('lock'));`). This approach, above, only presents an *illusion* of restriction, and then only to a relatively docile/disinterested user.